# Content Security Policy Error

Tags: javascript, cordova

Any suggestion why I cannot connect to a RESTful resource even though I've added it in the connect-src of the CSP. Below is the error message:

Refused to connect to **'http://api.pac-12.com/v2/events?sports=8&school=15'** because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' **http://api.pac-12.com/v2/***

Comment: Hello, I assume you have added this whole line ? <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * data: gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;script-src 'self' * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `Content-Security-Policy` tag from the `index.html`
and add the below lines in the `config.xml` within the `widget` tag

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```